# Dynamically create scheduler to trigger AWS services to read stream API

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket

My project requires reading stream API from our soccer match provider. We only can read this stream API when the match is about to start and keep the connection open until the match is completed. I'm currently stuck on how to implement and architect this as this is my first time handling this requirement. My rough idea is to store the matches' date and time inside dynamodb and then dynamically create eventbridge that will trigger AWS services suitable to read this stream API. I'm not sure whether lambda or EKS suitable for this project. The info from their FAQ "*a long-running socket connection MUST be used in order to digest the data from the READ stream*".

So in summary, my question is

1. Which AWS service I can use to read this stream API
2. How to trigger the above service by using eventbridge?

Need guidance and some idea from someone who is more experience and has done a similar kind of project in the past to guide me. Thank you.

Comment: IIRC Lambda has a 15 minute request limit, so that's out.